# Custom Style can't be detected on Dialog Constructor?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-styles

I have a custom style file(`style.xml`) in `res/values` that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I made it specially for **removing** the **default white frame** of my **dialog**.
But when I create the dialog object, `Eclipse` can,t find the style(`CustomDialogTheme`), as I supposed to pass it as the parameter of the `Dialog` Constructor(`Dialog(getParent(),android.R.style.CustomDialogTheme)`). I went one by one for the second parameter like Android.(then the menu comes up =>`R.style.`(now there is no style named `CustomDialogTheme`)).

What alternate should I use now and please don't suggest me to use `AlertDialog` as I already change it from `AlertDialog` to `Dialog`.

Comment: please change name of style.xml to any other name and then try with R.style.CustomDialogTheme .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you try with this

```
R.style.CustomDialogTheme only

Dialog(getParent(),R.style.CustomDialogTheme)
```

as `android.R.style` I think its define the predefine style into the android.R.style and whatever custom created layout, style or theme we use directly with the R.style which belongs to the current application